# how to remove positive infinity from numpy array...if it is already converted to a number?

Tags: python, numpy, infinity, graph-tool

How does one remove positive infinity numbers from a numpy array once these are already converted into a number format? I am using a package which uses numpy internally, however when returning certain arrays, certain values are returned as the 1.79769313486e+308 positive infinity number.

Is there an elegant and fast way to remove these (I would like '0' in my case), or is iterating through the array the best solution?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First of all, `1.79769313486e+308` is not the same as `+inf`. The former is the largest number which can be expressed with a 64-bit float, the latter is a special float.

If you just have very large numbers in your array, then:

```
A[A > 1e308] = 0
```

is sufficient. Thet'll replace oll elements above `1e308` with 0.

It is also possible to operate with the `inf`'s. For example:

```
>>> fmax = np.finfo(np.float64).max
>>> pinf = float('+inf')
>>> ninf = float('-inf')
>>> fnan = float('nan')
>>> print fmax, pinf, ninf, fnan
1.79769313486e+308 inf -inf nan
```

So, these are completely different things. You may compare some of them:

```
>>> pinf > fmax
True
>>> ninf < 0.0
True
>>> pinf == pinf
True
>>> pinf == ninf
False
```

This looks good! However, `nan` acts differently:

```
>>> fnan > 0
False
>>> fnan < 0
False
>>> fnan == 0
False
>>> fnan < pinf
False
>>> fnan == fnan
False
```

You may use positive and negativi infinities with Numpy `ndarray`without any problems. This will work:

```
A[A == pinf] = 0.0
```

But if you have `nan`s in the array, you'll get some complaints:

```
>>> np.array([fnan, pinf, ninf]) < 0
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
[False, False, True]
```

So, it works but complains => do not use. The same without the `nan`:

```
>>> np.array([0.0, pinf, ninf]) < 0
[False, False, True]
```

If you want to do something with the `nan`s (should you have them), use `numpy.isnan`:

```
A[np.isnan(A)] = 0.0
```

will change all `nan`s into zeros.

---

And -- this you did not ask -- here is one to surprise your friends (*):

```
>>> [float('-0.0'), 0.0] * 3
[-0.0, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0]
```

Yep, `float64` (and `float32`) have even a separate `-0.0`. In calculations it acts as an ordinary zero, though:

```
>>> float('-0.0') == 0.0
True
```

(*) Depending on the kind of people you call friends.

Answer (score 15):

To remove the very high values:

```
>>> a = numpy.array([1, 2, 1.8E308, 1.8E308, 42])
>>> a[a < 1E308] # use whatever threshold you like
array([  1.,   2.,  42.])
```

To set them 0:

```
>>> a = numpy.array([1, 2, 1.8E308, 1.8E308, 42])
>>> a[a >= 1E308] = 0
>>> a
array([  1.,   2.,   0.,   0.,  42.])
```